# Counting documents in firebase does not work

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a firebase query which counts the number of documents. I used the following code (from the firebase documentation):

```
const collectionRef = firestore.collection('tower');
const snapshot = await collectionRef.count().get();
console.log(snapshot.data().count);
```

I get the error :

> collectionRef.count is not a function.

When I delete count(), the query works.
I also tried npm i firebase-admin@latest which was mentioned in another post.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "reacttest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
    "expo": "~47.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "firebase": "^9.15.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^5.1.1",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-switch-selector": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { firestore } from './../firebase';
import { collection, query, where, onSnapshot, getDoc, getDocs, getAll } from "firebase/firestore";
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`? Firebase Admin is used on server side apps and not client. The count query is not supported by compat version of FIrebase SDK if you are using it. Also share the complete code so we can see the imports for the vars in above code snippet.

Comment: can try snapshot.data() only instead snapshot.data().count

Answer (score 0):

The COUNT() functionality is not available in the namespaced syntax of v8 and before. A quick scan of the [guide for the count operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries) and [reference documentation for `Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.Query) seems to confirm that.

To use COUNT() you'll have to use the modular syntax of v9 and above. For an example of that, see this [StackBlitz showing `count()`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/firestore-v9-count?file=index.js)

Comment: To add further clarification, the statement `collectionRef.count().get()` is only available for the [Google Cloud Firestore SDK](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#count) used by the Admin Node.JS SDK.